# changes in jquery 1.4.2 breaking the code?

Tags: jquery

I had this code on a page using jquery 1.3, but now in jquery 1.4.2 it's breaking with syntax error/uncrecognized expression:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span[@name^=charge]").click(function(){
        $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: shouldn't it be $("span[name^=\"charge\"]"). It looks to me like you're trying to use xpath syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@name has been deprecated - just use name now

See this thread:
http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg58250.html

Answer (score 1):

the only thing I see is that I generally don't use the '@' before defining my property, and I tend to put my property value selector in single quotes.  Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span[name^='charge']").click(function(){
        $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I do the opposite with quotes actually, i use single quotes for strings largely out of habit from php, then I can use double-quotes within them without worrying about character escaping nor output that would look weird (I hate having to type 'don\'t' or other contractions within a string though).

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax of your selector - I think that's supposed to be

```
 span[name^='charge']
```